# Making a copy of an object's initial state before saving

Tags: python, django, django-models

For my Django application, I'm looking to keep a full edit history for all objects.  As part of this, I've overridden the model's save() method, part of which is shown below:

```
# Replicate the current version (from the db) with all attributes unchanged
new_ver = self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk).save(force_insert=True)


# Update the current version in the database with the new attributes
super(CodexBaseClass, self).save(*args, force_update=True, **kwargs)
```

The 'self' that's passed to the save() method is the NEW version of the object that's been generated by the form.  What this code is attempting to do is

(1) Make a copy of the object as it currently appears in the database (ie: copy the data as it was before the form modified it), then force an insert of this data so it's copied as a new row

(2) Update the existing row with the new version of the object that's been submitted through the form.

The problem is with the first line of the two lines of code - It generates a DoesNotExist exception.  The object does exist, so I'm currently thinking that the issue is that the database row it's trying to read is currently locked.

So my question is: Is there a way I can modify/replace the first line so that I have a copy of the *initial* data, as it was before the form modified it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a new object with same attributes, you only need to change the primary key of your object, and save it.

> ```
> new_ver = self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
> new_ver.pk = None
> new_ver.save()
> ```

Using *None* as primary key will auto generates it. You can have more information if you look at the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances).

If you need you can also make a copy of your object, be careful the cost can be expensive :

> ```
> from copy import deepcopy
>
> ver = self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
> new_ver = deepcopy(ver)
> new_ver.pk = None
> new_ver.save()
> # Do what you need with ver object
> ```

Comment: I've tried exactly that.  It gives the same exception.

    self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk)

is the part that seems to be the problem.  The object referenced by self.pk is the object that's being edited by the UpdateView, so it seems I can't read that particular object from the database at this point... at least not with this method.

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

**You should take a look at [django-reversion](https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-reversion/).**

> django-reversion is an extension to the Django web framework that
>   provides version control for model instances.

**Documentation**: [link](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

**Features**

- Roll back to any point in a model instance’s history.
- Recover deleted model instances.
- Simple admin integration.